Can `${...}` properties appear in the `<parent>` section of a POM file?
Maven's POM reference says that property values "are accessible anywhere within a POM".
But that can't possibly be 100% true. The resolved value of a property depends on the POM's parent, so using a property in the <parent> section seems like it would create a circular dependency:

To know the parent's coordinates you need the parent's properties
To know the parent's properties you need the parent's coordinates

For example, is it legal to write
    <parent>
      <groupId>my.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>${project-prefix}-common</artifactId>
      <version>xyz</version>
    </parent>

And if so, what value does Maven use for ${project-prefix}?
Maven's own documentation suggests that properties can be used in a <parent> section, but in my own experimentation (Maven 3.9.8) I've found the behavior nigh-impossible to predict (at least for me, a POM novice).
Are properties actually allowed in the <parent> section? Also, is there any official documentation on how properties within a <parent> section are supposed to work?

I don't understand that: To know the parent's coordinates you need the parent's properties The coordinates are given via groupId/artifactId/version but why do you need the properties ?

Suppose I write <parent><artifactId>${some-property}</artifactId>...</parent>. Wouldn't you need the value of some-property to get the coordinates?

Yes but in a parent you never write a property nor does it make sense... because if that property is inherited from the parent that means your have a cyclic dependency ... What is the use case of that? The documentation is writing about the version and NOT about the groupId/artifactId furthermore it is required to use a property names in the section of that page... within a mutl module build the groupId/artifactId will not change so it makes only sense to define the version via the property... see the ci firendly documentation....

<parent>...<version>${some-property}</version></parent> has the same problem as groupId/artifactId, no? Different versions of a parent POM might declare different values for a property.

In the documentation there is clearly stated that you can only use revision,sha1 and changelist no other properties for that...also an example project would be helpful...

When the CI Friendly Versions says "You can only use those named ${revision}, ${sha1} and/or ${changelist}" it means you can only use those "as placeholders for the version in your pom file."
If anything that makes me more nervous! Nevermind the <parent> section---now I think there are restrictions to what properties I can put in my POM's <version>, which I did not expect.
Is the full set of restrictions documented? The CI Friendly Versions page is really a release note, and is not linked anywhere from the Maven User Centre: https://maven.apache.org/users/index.html

The restriction simply exists. Those are the facts.. it's nothing to think about... is the way it is... The missing link is also a fact... need to fix that... (Ok created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-539)


Maven's POM reference says that property values "are accessible anywhere within a POM".

Yes, this is true.

But that can't possibly be 100% true. The resolved value of a property depends on the POM's parent, so using a property in the  section seems like it would create a circular dependency:

To know the parent's coordinates you need the parent's properties
To know the parent's properties you need the parent's coordinates


You confuse circular dependencies with property values resolving. These are based on distinct mechanisms. While I don't know the internals of Maven, the parent POM can access a property value defined in its descendant.

Example
Here is a simplified example I use in an unnamed project:
Parent POM
Properties (the jib-maven-plugin.to.image property is resolved in the children):
<properties>
    <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry/>
    <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-artefact/>
    <jib-maven-plugin.to.image>${jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry}${jib-maven-plugin.to.image-artefact}</jib-maven-plugin.to.image>

    ...
</properties>

Usage:
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <skip>${jib-maven-plugin.skip}</skip>
            <from>
                <image>${jib-maven-plugin.from.image}</image>
                <platforms>
                    <platform>
                        <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                        <os>linux</os>
                    </platform>
                </platforms>
            </from>
            <to>
                <image>${jib-maven-plugin.to.image}</image>
                <auth>
                    <username>${env.HARBOR_USERNAME}</username>
                    <password>${env.HARBOR_PASSWORD}</password>
                </auth>
                <tags>
                    <tag>latest</tag>
                    <tag>${docker-images.version}-${buildDate}</tag>
                    <tag>${docker-images.version}-${buildDate}-${buildNumber}</tag>
                </tags>
            </to>
            <container>
                <creationTime>USE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</creationTime>
                <mainClass>${main-class}</mainClass>
                <user>nobody</user>
                <workingDirectory>/app/resources</workingDirectory>
                <labels>
                    <org.opencontainers.image.vendor>Vendor</org.opencontainers.image.vendor>
                    <org.opencontainers.image.title>Title</org.opencontainers.image.title>
                    <org.opencontainers.image.description>Description</org.opencontainers.image.description>
                    <org.opencontainers.image.version>${project.version}</org.opencontainers.image.version>
                </labels>
            </container>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>${jib-maven-plugin.goal}</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    ...
</plugins>

Children POMs
foo (child 1) pom.xml:
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker-local</id>
        <properties>
            <jib-maven-plugin.skip>false</jib-maven-plugin.skip>
            <jib-maven-plugin.goal>dockerBuild</jib-maven-plugin.goal>
            <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry/>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>docker-harbor</id>
        <properties>
            <jib-maven-plugin.skip>false</jib-maven-plugin.skip>
            <jib-maven-plugin.goal>build</jib-maven-plugin.goal>
            <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry>mycompany-1.com/foo/</jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

bar (child 2) pom.xml:
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>docker-local</id>
        <properties>
            <jib-maven-plugin.skip>false</jib-maven-plugin.skip>
            <jib-maven-plugin.goal>dockerBuild</jib-maven-plugin.goal>
            <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry/>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>docker-harbor</id>
        <properties>
            <jib-maven-plugin.skip>false</jib-maven-plugin.skip>
            <jib-maven-plugin.goal>build</jib-maven-plugin.goal>
            <jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry>mycompany-1.com/bar/</jib-maven-plugin.to.image-registry>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>


Sorry, maybe my question wasn't clear. Your examples do not include cases where the <parent> section in the child uses properties. For instance, what does <parent><artifactId>${some-property}</artifactId>...</parent> mean?
(I will amend the question to clarify this.)
